# C++ program not working when entering more than certain lines of input

Tags: c++, xcode

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int size = 0;
    int numbers[10000];
    while (scanf("%i", &numbers[size]) != EOF) {
        size++;
    }
    //some other functions...
    return 0;
}
```

It is to solve a problem for competitive programming, and when entering the input(more than 1000 lines) to debug, it just stays there and never finishes. But if I enter just a part of the same input(more less 300 lines) it works propperly. Any ideas? I'm using Xcode.

Comment: Off-topic: why `scanf` instead of `while (std::cin >> numbers[size++]);`?

Comment: You example uses `scanf` without including the appropriate header. It shouldn't even compile successfully.

Comment: Have a look at the actual input around the vicinity of the 300th line (or whatever line it is where the behaviour changes) and see if it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) returns the number variables it was able to fill - however, this can even be 0 (zero) - if you enter some characters scanf cannot parse. If this happens, though, scanf will try to re-read one and the same input all the time, resulting in an endless loop.

Try this for illustration:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int n;
    int r = scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d / %d\n", r, n);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

and give input some numbers, then a non-decimal (e. g. `7 8 x`).

So prefer `while (scanf("%i", &numbers[size]) == 1)` instead.